# Include another file in Postfix proxy configuration

Tags: postfix

I am trying to configure Postfix with FreeIPA and need to provide the bind DN, base DN, password, servers etc. for LDAP proxies. These need to go into four different configuration files, making it a hard-to-maintain mess. Is it possible to include another file from proxy configuration file (`smtpd_sender_login_maps`, `virtual_mailbox_domains`, `virtual_mailbox_maps`, `virtual_alias_maps`) in Postfix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix has no inclusion mechanism for config files.  The best you could do is using a configuration management tool (like salt, ansible, chef, or puppet) or to create the files through some other automated means.  A Makefile and the m4 macroprocessor would be decent, conservative choices.

You might be able to use a simple PCRE regexp file as `smtpd_sender_login_maps`.  See e.g. [this server fault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/318334/how-to-enforce-sender-address-to-be-logged-in-userexample-org-in-postfix).